# bash / awk workflow operating on multi-column files

Tags: bash, awk

I am working on the improvement of the bash-awk workflow designed for the analysis of data in multiple-colums format. The script uses AWK code (which extract numbers from selected columns of the input.csv as well as does some basic stat calculations) integrated into bash script (which operates with the input files located in different folders):

```
#!/bin/bash
home="$PWD"
# folder with the outputs
rescore="${home}"/rescore 
# folder with the folders to analyse
storage="${home}"/results
csv_pattern='*_filt.csv'
str_name='output.csv'


while read -r d; do
#awk -F, '                       # set field separator to comma
awk -F ", *" '                  # set field separator to comma, followed by 0 or more whitespaces
FNR==1 {
   if (n) {                     # calculate the results of previous file
      m = s / n                 # mean
      var = s2 / n - m * m      # variance
      if (var < 0) var = 0      # avoid an exception due to round-off error
      mean[suffix] = m          # store the mean in an array
      rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)
      lowest[suffix] = min      # lowest dG
      highest[suffix] = fourth  # dG in cluster with highest pop
   }
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s = 0                        # sum of $3
   s2 = 0                       # sum of $3 ** 2
   n = 0                        # count of samples
   min = 0                      # lowest value of $3 (assuming all $3 < 0)
   max = 0                      # highest value of $2 (assuming all $2 > 0)
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   s2 += $3 * $3
   ++n
   if ($3 < min) min = $3       # update the lowest value
   if ($2 > max) {
      max = $2                  # update popMAX
      fourth = $3               # update the value of dG corresponded to topPOP
   }
}
END {
  if (n) {                     # just to avoid division by zero
   m = s / n
   var = s2 / n - m * m
   if (var < 0) var = 0
   mean[suffix] = m
   rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)
   lowest[suffix] = min     # most negative dG
   highest[suffix] = fourth  # dG in a cluster with pop(MAX)
  }
   print "Lig(CNE)", "dG(" prefix ")", "dG(popMAX)"
   for (i in mean)
      printf "%s %.2f %.2f\n", i, lowest[i],  highest[i]
}'  "${d}_"*/${str} > "${rescore}/${str_name}/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
```

Basically, the script operates with input.csv (shown below), extracting numbers from the third column (dG): i) detecting the minimal value in the third column (dG(min) which always corresponds to the line with ID=1), as well as the number of the dG corresponded to the maximal number in the second column (POPmax):

```
# input *_filt.csv located in the folder 10V1_cne_lig12
ID, POP, dG
1, 142, -5.6500 # this is dG min to be extracted
2, 10, -5.5000
3, 2, -4.9500
4, 150, -4.1200 # this is dG corresponded to pop(MAX) to be extracted
```

finally it saves the results in another multi-column output file, contained a part of the name of each processed CSV (with corresponded prefix used as the ID of the line), as well as information regarding its dG(min) and dG(popMAX). For 5 processed input.csvs it will countain 5 lines and 3 columns with name of the initial file, dG(min) as well as dG(corresponded to popMAX):

```
# output.csv
Lig(CNE)    dG(min) dG(popMAX)
lig12       -5.65   -4.12      # this line from the input.csv shown above !
lig40       -5.52   -5.52
lig199      -4.81   -4.81
lig211      -5.28   -5.28
lig278      -5.76   -5.76
```

I need to modify the AWK part of my script in order to add two additional columns to the output.csv contained information regarding POP (the number from the second column of the inout.csv) for each of the corresponded dG value (the has been taken from the 3rd column of the same log). So the same log should be like this

```
# output.csv
Lig(CNE).   dG(min) POP(min)    dG(popMAX) POP(max)
lig12       -5.65   (142)       -4.12      (150) # this is both dG and POP from input.csv
lig40       -5.52   (30)         -5.52     (34)
lig199      -4.81   (111)        -4.81    (300)
lig211      -5.28   (4)          -5.28      (12)
lig278      -5.76   (132)        -5.76    (150)
```

Comment: Just a reminder that this is Code Review, we review working code to help you improve that code. We can't help you add new features such as 2 new columns to the output.

Comment: Right thank you! In fact this code is fully OK but as it can be seen it was written focusing primarily on the operations mame on the third column. So the problem is to adapt it for multi-column tasks ..

Comment: Code Review isn't about helping you modify your code for new requirements, it is about helping you to see better logic.  We Review code here, Code that is already written and fulfilling all requirements.